# Is this really malware in react native?

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

I have an big issue. I need update something to the application but I can't do that because `yarn install` keeps failing because virus protection software keeps removing it.

`Error: Failed to open the cache entry for @react-native/assets@npm:1.0.0: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/admin/Desktop/AwesomeProject/.yarn/cache/@react-native-assets-npm-1.0.0-2165b2ba43-4525dd1704.zip`

[image]

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Tried to create another react native project with 0.69 version but resulted still with same issue.

Comment: I really faced many issues with yarn. npm is a better approach.

Comment: @MishenThakshana I usually had issues with npm. Npm not having interactive tools is lacking and takes quite time to update dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps:

1: Run in terminal - yarn cache clean

2- Delete the specific cache entry: In your case, it seems that the error is related to the cache entry for @react-native/assets@npm:1.0.0. You can manually delete this cache entry by removing the corresponding zip file. In your case, it's located at /Users/admin/Desktop/AwesomeProject/.yarn/cache/@react-native-assets-npm-1.0.0-2165b2ba43-4525dd1704.zip. Delete this file and then try running yarn install again.

3: Use the --ignore-scripts flag: If the error persists, you can try running yarn install with the --ignore-scripts flag to skip running any scripts during the installation process. This can help bypass any issues related to scripts failing or being blocked by your virus protection software. Run the following command:

yarn install --ignore-scripts

Comment: Yarn 2 doesnt seem to support --ignore-scripts